# add more picture instead of replacing picture in asp.net core mvc

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

i create a form where i upload picture into database in asp.net core mvc using ado.net.i face an issue that when i select picture it selects the picture but if i do one more time instead of add more picture it replace that picture which i select first help me to that thing in which i add further more picture. i create a list in which i upload the picture.Here is my code.
My Controller:

public IActionResult aprent([Bind] RentModel ar )

```
    {
        
        try
        {
            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(ar.imge1 != null && ar.imge1.Count>0)
        {
                    string folder = "image/";
                    foreach (IFormFile imge in ar.imge1)
                    {
                        folder += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + imge.FileName;




                        ar.pic1 = "/" + folder;

                        string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
                        imge.CopyTo(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
                    }

                }
                string res = DB.Saverecord(ar);
                string pics = DB.imagedb(ar);

                

                
                TempData["msg"] = res;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["msg"] = ex.Message;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My Model:

```
        public string? pic1 { get; set; }
        

        public IFormFileCollection imge1 { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
<div class="row">

                <input type="file" name="imge1" id="file" asp-for="imge1" class="hidden" multiple>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="filebutton"><span id="filetext">Select File</span></button>
                <div id="preview"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="image_preview"></div>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#filebutton').click(function () {
                $('#file').click();
            });

            $('#file').change(function () {

                var name = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
                var file = $(this)[0].files;
                if (name != '') {
                    if (file.length >= 2) {
                        $('#filetext').html(file.length + ' files ready to upload');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#filetext').html(name);
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#file').on("change", previewImages);
        });

        function previewImages() {

            var $preview = $('#preview').empty();
            if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

            function readAndPreview(i, file) {

                if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
                    return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
                } // else...

                var reader = new FileReader();

                $(reader).on("load", function () {
                    $preview.append($("<img>", { src: this.result, height: 80, }));
                });

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: "when i select picture it selects the picture but if i do one more time instead of add more picture it replace that picture which i select first'" When and where do you  do one more time select? Besides, what's your  form that you upload picture into database  look like?

Comment: i mean it selects pictures just one time means in the frontend in the form where i upload after selecting picture if i again press choose picture instead of add more picture it replace those picture which i select before this all action perform before posting the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to choose more  pictures at  one time ?

Something like below? Hold down the `Shift` key when you choose   pictures.

**Update**

> if i select picture and after that i hit the choose button one more
> time it select further more picture but not replace the previous
> selected picture
>
> i have also other data also i have same model in which my data exist
> when i post form

You can try to use [jQuery FilePond](https://github.com/pqina/jquery-filepond).

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

TestController:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
       
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Testmodel testmodel,IFormFile[] photos)
        {
            
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Testmodel:

```
public class Testmodel
    {   
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public IList<IFormFile> photos { get; set; }
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model Testmodel
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-filepond/filepond.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>

<form id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" asp-for="Name" />   
<input  type="file" class="filepond"asp-for="photos">
<button type="submit" class="uploadbtn">Upload Document</button>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
pond = FilePond.create(
    document.querySelector('.filepond'), {
        allowMultiple: true,
        instantUpload: false,
        allowProcess: false
    });

$("#uploadform").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formdata = new FormData(this);
  // append FilePond files into the form data
  pondFiles = pond.getFiles();
  for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++) {
      // append the blob file
      formdata.append('photos', pondFiles[i].file);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/Index",
    data: formdata,    
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    method:"post"    
  });
 
})
});
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: No i know that thing the thing i want that if i select picture and after that i hit the choose button one more time it select further more picture but not replace the previous selected picture

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean now.

Comment: Ok,if you have any solution then tell me

Comment: it works but there is a problem in controller public IActionResult aprent([Bind] RentModel ar, IFormFile[] imge1) so i have not only the images in form i have also other data also i have same model in which my data exist when i post form i have error of model state is null because it RentModel ar has also imge1 is there any solution for it

Comment: also i want preview of images before upload

Comment: @CreativeThings I add a Name in the model, then use `<input type="text" asp-for="Name" /> ` .You can refer to it to add your data.

Comment: i dont understand kindly explain it

Comment: @CreativeThings "i have also other data " If you want to pass other data at the same time, you can add in the form, just like my demo. But "preview of images before upload" ,I don't know how to do it now.

Comment: kindly tell me how to customly design this

Comment: @CreativeThings   What do you mean  about  " customly design this" ? Could you  explain more ?

Comment: it means i want the picture added in the list will show in row not in column

Comment: i also want to preview the image